# Titanium TabGroup control "more" tab not rendering properly

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm upgrading a Titanium app to SDK 5.1.2GA and noticed that the "more" tab of our TabGroup control isn't displaying properly. This "more" tab is automatically generated by the TabGroup control because we have more tabs than will fit in the row at the bottom of the screen. Here's what it looks like in SDK 5.1.2GA:

[image: New SDK]

.. and here's what it's looked like in older SDKs. The code hasn't changed:

[image: Old SDK]

Comment: Just to clarify, the "More" tab is being automatically generated by the TabGroup control by design. I do not have the "more" tab in my Alloy XML or controllers therefore I do not have any control over it's width, design, etc. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: It seems, the both more buttons are absolutely similar. Where's the difference?

Comment: The problem isn't the "more" tab button, it's the way the actual tab renders. See the additional tabs that render in the large white area on both screens: Training, Notifications, Support, Settings.

Comment: Ok, now seeing the difference. I would suggest you file a ticket on https://jira.appcelerator.org